# Query with specific value returns no rows when I run it within php code

Tags: php, mysql

Here is how I create the link to the page

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/wiki/city/<?php echo urlencode($city); ?>" ><?php echo urlencode($city); ?></a>
```

Here is what url looks like for this particular city:

```
http://www.site.com/wiki/city/Qazvin+%28city%29
```

On the target page, when I try to get this city from database it returns false. It doesn't find any rows.

```
    SELECT * from citys WHERE title = 'Qazvin (city)'
    boolean false
(i print out the query in the page  )
```

If I copy and run it from PHPMyAdmin SQL console it will return couple of rows. I only have the problem with this particular city

I'm using a MVC framework

Controller:

```
 public function city($title=' '){ 

     $title = urldecode($title); 
     $city  = $this->m_wiki->getCITY( $title );
     echo $this->db->last_query();
     var_dump($city);
}
```

Model:

```
    public function getCITY($title){    
        $city =  $this->db->query("SELECT * from citys WHERE  title = '$title'");
        if($city->num_rows() > 0 )
        return $city;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: 1. why are there two `return` statements? 2. Why are you concatenating SQL queries? 3. What is your question?

Comment: The two return statements are there because the first belongs to the preceding `if` which does not have curly braces. This is a bad habit for "quick" programming and should result in a fatal error, but sadly does not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `urldecode()` - it's wrong there because PHP already did this for you automatically.

DO escape your query! That part is missing, but must be done, because not only is it essential for security, but will also make your query work with non-standard characters.